# React llamar funciones que renderizan componente

Tags: reactjs

Estoy creando un componente de tipo Toast para control de notificaciones, no quiero agregarlo a dom como:

```
<Toast title="notification" visible={state.toast} />
```

me parece poco practico y trendria que crear estados.

Como podria hacerlo utilizando una llamada de esta manera:

```
toast.info({title: 'notification'});
```

> Componente Toast.

```
export const Toast = ({title}) => {
 return <div className="toast">
   {title}
 </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma puede ser envolver `Toast` en **curly braces {}** para poder usarlo como una expresión `javascript`:

```js
function App(){
  function test(){
      console.log(Toast({title: 'notification'}));
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={test}>test</button>
      {/*Toast({title: 'notification'})*/}
    </div>
  )
}

const Toast = ({title}) => {
  return <div className="toast">
    {title}
  </div>
 }

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Ahora, aunque se llame de esta forma, el `div` en `Toast` es un **[Elemento ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)** y sigue siendo parte del **[Virtual DOM tree](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)** de ReactJS.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Preferiblemente quiero llamarlo dentro de una funcion y no dentro del return

Comment: Interesante, entonces tu componente `Toast`, no forma parte del render, tampoco necesita regresar ningún elemento, solo propiedades, en este caso solo quieres regresar `title` ¿Ese es tu caso de uso?

Comment: No, necesito que se llame el elemento de manera dinamica en una funcion sin tener que meterlo al render

Comment: Actualice la respuesta, es lo más que se me ocurre por ahora, en el `console.log` se obtiene un `typeof react Element`, saludos